# TestScheduler for subject

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-test-scheduler

I am trying to call `.next` on a simple subject `submitTask$`.

My pipeline is this:

```
export const submitTask$ = new Subject();

function epic() {
  return submitTask$.pipe(
    map(taskId => {
        console.log('here');
        return Boolean(taskId)
    })
  )
}
```

I am trying to use TestScheduler to test this but cannot figure out how. I tried this:

```
const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  expect(actual).toStrictEqual(expected);
});

testScheduler.run(({ hot, expectObservable }) => {

const actions$ = hot('-', [() => submitTask$.next(task.id)]);

const output$ = epic();

expectObservable(output$).toBe('0', [true]);
```

However it is not working, I am never seeing the `console.log('here')`

Comment: The RxJS `Subject` is a special type of `Observable`. If there is no subscription to an `Observer` the pipe of it won't be evaluated. So I think a `subscribe` method is needed for the `output$` in the test. (I did not use `TestScheduler` yet, that's why I'm sure if it changes something on the default behaviour.) Here is what I tested on stackblitz without `TestScheduler`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my-demo-starter-77tf72?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're not subscribing `actions$`. Also, I'm not sure `[() => submitTask$.next(task.id)]` will do anything.

You could try this:

```js
testScheduler.run(({ /* ... */ }) => {
  const s = new Subject();

  const src = hot('    --a', { a: 1 /* task.id */ });
  const expectedSrc = '--1';

  const epicObs = cold('-s').pipe(mergeMapTo(epic())); // Subscribe to the subject, before the value is emitted
  const expectedEpic = '--v';
  const epicValues = { v: true };

  expectObservable(src.pipe(tap(id => s.next(id)))).toBe(expectedSrc);
  expectObservable(epicObs).toBe(expectedEpic, epicValues);
});
```